# How to add text between other text?

Tags: sql, concatenation, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to add text between other text in a table. For example, the column is varchar(10) and it always has text that is 8 characters. I want to make a procedure that adds two zeros(00) between the sixth and the seventh character.

For example:
'gr123465' to become 'gr12340065'

I don't know a statement that does that. I know lpad and rpad, but I don't think they will help.

I didn't try anything yet because I can't find a statement that does that. Maybe `||`? I don't know. I'm not very good at SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OVERLAY` function](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-overlay) for this:

```sql
select overlay(data placing '00' from 7 for 0)
from (select 'gr123465' as data from rdb$database)

-- Result is: gr12340065
```

(dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZD9tB8VC)

The `overlay(data placing '00' from 7 for 0)` will insert the text `00` at the seventh character position of `data`, the `for 0` means that following text should not be overwritten, but that the new value should be inserted instead.

If you want to do it more manual or explicit, you can also use [`SUBSTRING`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring):

```sql
select substring(data from 1 for 6) || '00' || substring(data from 7)
from (select 'gr123465' as data from rdb$database)

-- Result: gr12340065
```

(dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/H3e0Bx9I)

Comment: Thanks man I used overlay but i didnt know that with 'for' you can insert instead of just replace. Thank you again

Comment: @KirilHristov You're welcome. The `for` argument controls how many characters will be overwritten. It defaults to the length of the `placing` argument, but you can also overwrite more or less characters (including none with `for 0`). See also the examples in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.